# "open" command doesn't work properly inside tmux

Tags: macos, tmux, mutt

I am trying to use the `open` command to open a link in Chrome from my terminal.

It works fine in plain Terminal.app or iTerm2, but doesn't work properly from tmux. What happens is: it opens a new instance of Chrome (rather than opening a new tab) and doesn't actually go to the URL.

Is there any fix for this? The reason I need this functionality is for running Mutt with urlview to open the links from emails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a problem that could be solved by installing [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard).

If you don't wanna get deep into manually solving this problem you can use one of the tmux plugins:

- [tmux-urlview](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-urlview) looks like exactly what you're looking for
- another solution is to use [tmux-copycat](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-copycat) + [tmux-open](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-open)

Comment: Thank you so much! Installing [reattach-to-user-namespace](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) solved the problem.